# How to get clean mark-up from AngularJS template conditionals

Tags: angularjs, templates

I need some guidelines on how to produce clean mark-up when using Angular conditionals.

On my team, I'm the go-to CSS guy. Sometimes I get mark-up that's much more complex and nested than it needs to be, and I take it upon myself to clean it up.

For example, I just re-factored the following mark-up from this:

```
<div ng-show="isGroupingActive()">
    <div style="padding-left: {[{ getPadding(row) }]}px;">
        <div ng-show="row.children"
             ng-click="showHideGroup(row)">
                <div ng-switch on="row.expanded">
                    <div ng-switch-when="true">+</div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="false">-</div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-hide="row.children">
            .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div ng-if="row.children && row.expanded"
      ng-click="showHideGroup(row)"
      style="padding-left: {[{ getPadding(row) }]}px;">-</div>

<div ng-if="row.children && !row.expanded"
      ng-click="showHideGroup(row)"
      style="padding-left: {[{ getPadding(row) }]}px;">+</div>

<div ng-if="!row.children"
      style="padding-left: {[{ getPadding(row) }]}px;">.</div>
```

I much prefer the single DOM element produced by version 2 over the unnecessary complexity of the nested DOM in the original. Further, I think this logic is far more readable and maintainable.

Comparing the two versions, it occurred to me that my colleague was writing HTML the same way he might write the conditionals in JavaScript (where he is more comfortable). He was observing DRY principles. Notice how my version repeats itself a few times. If we were to add more conditions, we'd have to repeat ourselves some more. Still, version 2 yields much cleaner, simpler HTML.

So my question: How do you react to my revision, and what is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Can you just add a dynamic class using ng-class based on the conditions you want and then set the icon text using css content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the AngularJS Google group, here's the final implementation:

```
<i ng-click="showHideGroup(row)"
   ng-class="getToggleIcon(row)"
   class="treeToggle"
   style="padding-left: {[{ getPadding(row) }]}px;">
</i>
```

I opted to use fontawesome icons instead of '+' / '-' / '.' as content inside of a div.

Meanwhile, the logic was moved to scope (much cleaner...):

```
$scope.getToggleIcon = function(item) {
    var expandedIconClass   = 'fa fa-minus-square-o',
        collapsedIconClass  = 'fa fa-plus-square-o',
        noChildrenIconClass = '';

    if (item.children) {
        return item.expanded ? expandedIconClass : collapsedIconClass;
    } else {
        return noChildrenIconClass;
    }
};
```